# About the type const char* and the name of the char array

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class String {
    private :
        const char * str; // declaration "char str[30];" is appropriate
    public :
        String(const char * _str) {
            str = new char[30];
            strcpy(str, _str);
        }
}; 

int main() {
    const char* sz = "Hello!";
    String s("Hi!");
    s = sz;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a question for the types `const char *` and char array.
What I know is that "the name of a char array" has the same type as "the `const char *` variable".
So, as what i wrote in the above code, I thought it would be compiled properly.
But the compiler rejects my code, because the function `strcpy()` doesn't support conversion from the type `const char *` to the type `char`*.
What's wrong with this situation? Am I having wrong C++ grammatical knowledge?

Comment: You are wrong. The name of a char array decays to `char * const` pointer.

Comment: You cannot copy to a const array. That's what const means: no modifications allowed.

Comment: First, array names do not have the same type as "const pointer to array element type", but decay to that. Second, `const` qualifiers should always be treated properly. The only way to remove the qualifier (*at your own risk*) is to use `const_cast`. So yes, you *are* having wrong C++ grammatical knowledge.

Comment: You say you know "the name of a char array" has the same type as "the `const char *` variable".   Wrong, wrong, wrong.   The name of a any array has type equal to an array of elements.   For example, `"Hello!"`  has type `char [7]` (it is a statically allocated array of 7 `char`, which allows for the trailing nul character). But an array is a completely different type from a pointer.  The name of an array can be *converted* to a pointer to its first element, which is why `const char* sz = "Hello!";` works - it causes `sz` to point at the first character in the string literal i.e. to the `'H'`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But one thing i wanna know is that how could I make type casting through constructor with `=` operator which exerts implicit conversion? Is it the only way to declare `char str[30];` instead of `const char* str` leading to use `new` keyword? I don't want to allocate memory in stack space though..

Comment: *"the compiler rejects my code, because the function* `strcpy()` *doesn't support conversion from the type* `const char *` *to the type* `char*`". Compiler warnings have become incredibly good at identifying and detailing the exact cause of the problem. A `const` qualified pointer does not mean you cannot change the pointer address, it means you cannot change what resides in the pointed-to memory.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `new char[30]` is of type `char*` and you would have no problems copying something to the allocation using `strcpy` (although it's definitely not something you should be doing, since it's an open invitation to buffer overflow). The problem is that you immediately assign that pointer to `str` and `str` has type `const char*`. `const` is constant; you can't assign to a `const`, which is what `strcpy` will do.

In fact, assigning the pointer to a `const char*` member doesn't magically change the nature of the memory pointed to. If you were able to call `strcpy`, for example by `const_cast`ing the first argument, then nothing would break. The memory is writable. But the compiler won't let you write to it through a `const char*` because declaring a pointer to be `const char*` is a promise that you won't try to write to the memory. And it's a promise which you immediately break.

Anyway, you can do the following, at no extra cost:

```cpp
class String {
    private :
        const char * str; // declaration "char str[30];" is appropriate
    public :
        String(const char * _str) {
            char * cpy = new char[strlen(_str) + 1];
            str = strcpy(cpy, _str);
        }
};
```

Comment: Oh my, I would have been confused with the literal meaning of `const`.... thought it was something peculiar. Thanks for your help. But one more thing i wanna know - an obvious, easily expected questions to be answered : is there any way to initialize `const char*` type member? I heard that except `const char*` type, it is possible to initiallize `const` type member variables such as `const int` through the member initializer notation.(e.g. `void egFunc(int _member1) : member1(_member1) {}` supposing `const int member1`) I guess the answer is 'No'.. but I hope it to be yes.

Comment: @ragedhumancompiler: Of course you can initialize a `const char*`, but I don't think that's what you really want to know. In C (and C++) a pointer is an object in and of itself, and you can initialize it as you see fit. I'm sure you've heard this all a hundred times but it's important so I'll repeat it again: you must distinguish between a pointer and what it points at. A `const char*` member is not itself `const` (that would be `const char* const`), so you can reassign it to point at a different block of memory.

Comment: A pointer points to a block of memory. To initialise a pointer, you must have the address of the block of memory it points to. That's somewhat independent of initialising the block of memory itself, but you probably also want to do that before you assign the pointer to point at the block of memory. You could do all that by initializing the pointer to `strcpy(new char[strlen(_str)+1], _str)`: look carefully at the return value of `strcpy` to see how that works. But I wouldn't actually recommend doing that. I suggest you use `std::string` if you're going to program in C++.

Comment: Thanks again. It is quite demanding not to inappropriately use the pointer.. I must practice more.